# Error in API bigquery.jobs.query() while using TABLE_DATE_RANGE

Tags: google-bigquery

---

In the recent two days I got an error in my process which worked successfully on a daily base in the recent year.

The bigquery.jobs.query() is not recognize the TABLE_DATE_RANGE (table wildcard function).

This is my **Request** (After I changed my ID):

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/foo/queries?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer XXXXXX
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{

 "query": "SELECT COUNT( 1)  AS CNT FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(DEV.FACT_,TIMESTAMP('20141018'),TIMESTAMP('20141019'))",
 "dryRun": true,
 "kind": "bigquery#queryRequest",
 "defaultDataset": {
  "datasetId": "DEV"
 }
}
```

This is the response:

```
404 Not Found

- Hide headers -

cache-control:  private, max-age=0
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  146
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Sun, 19 Oct 2014 07:54:53 GMT
expires:  Sun, 19 Oct 2014 07:54:53 GMT
server:  GSE

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found: Table foo:DEV.FACT_"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found: Table foo:DEV.FACT_"
 }
}
```

When I Execute the query in the browser I get result.
When I remove the dryRun Attribute or set it to be False I get the result (200 OK)

Can Google explain what is the reason for this ?

Regards,

Liad

Comment: Got the same symptoms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report.
It looks like TABLE_DATE_RANGE resolution is broken for dry run queries. I've filed a bug, we should have a fix soon. If you'd like to track the resolution, you can file a bug in the public issue tracker here: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/.

Comment: Filed bug http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=169&q=label%3DBugs